# How to run electron-rebuild from my gulp task?

Tags: node.js, gulp, electron

I'm working on electron application and want to add sqlite3 database to it. 
There is a problem with native modules in electron, so I need to run electron-rebuild after npm install.
What I have now:

```
gulp.task('nb:dist-node-modules', [], function(){
    return gulp.src('./package.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_APP))
        .pipe(install({ production: true }));
});
```

What I want to add:

```
gulp.task('nb:dist-node-modules-rebuild', ['nb:dist-node-modules'], function(){
    //var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var exec = require('gulp-exec');
    exec(DIST_APP + '/node_modules/.bin/' + 'electron-rebuild.cmd');    
});
```

The problem is that electron-rebuild.cmd doesn't work in this way. Although, when I run it manually from cmd, it works fine.

I think general question is - how to run .cmd file from gulp task.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First, the answer to your "main" question is- do **NOT** run the electron CMD from your gulp task.

The reason for this is that `electron-rebuild` can be called directly via its own API from inside of `gulp`. You do not need to launch an `exec` or go off process and attempt a command line run.

As an example, here is a simple version of a gulp task that does electron rebuild based on the configuration found from the currently running version of node (executing the gulp script) and the version of electron installed in the  package's local node_modules.  If you are using the standard project directory structure, this should be a good starting place for a gulp task for rebuilding with electron without too much trouble.

```
var electronPackage = require('electron/package.json');
// pull the electron version from the package.json file
var electronVersion = electronPackage.version;

gulp.task('erebuild', function () {

    var eRebuild = require('electron-rebuild');
    var process = require('process');
    var arch = process.arch;

    eRebuild.default(__dirname, electronVersion, arch)
        .then(function () {
            console.info('Electron Rebuild Successful');
            return true;
        }).catch(function(e) {
            log('Rebuilding modules against Electron didn\'t work: ' + e);
        });
});
```

IMO, the package documentation isn't super clear about the API *order* but they infer it by the order listed in their options overview here: https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild#how-can-i-integrate-this-into-grunt--gulp--whatever

I only use the first 3 arguments in my example above, but supposedly all of them work. In previous versions of this API, I found that building 32bit Windows executables while running in a gulp script called from a 64bit Windows version of Node didn't work, but I haven't checked to see if that is fixed in the most recent version.